# Session cookie keeps getting overwritten

Tags: cakephp-2.0

When I log into my application I get a cookie with a value of say odm7krain1ms6bic7irfvpsj91 .

as long as I stay on this tab and move through the application I'm "usually" okay. If I open another tab and go the same url, I'll get a new cookie that overwrites the old one and my old session is lost. How can I prevent this from happening?

I've seen this happen when I'm using XHR requests also which effectivly logs me out of my current session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your core.php file:

```
Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', false);
Configure::write('Session.ini',array('session.cookie_secure' => false, 'session.referer_check' => false));
```

These parameters should force the cookie to persist. This will set both PHP and CakePHP's settings to allow cookies to persist over http and https.

Comment: This put me on the correct path so thanks.  I had accidentally commented one of those lines in the core.

Answer (score 0):

use $_SESSION["your session var"];